# How to output to a compiler's console and how to stop the build when an error occurs from an external tool?

Tags: build-process, compiler-construction

I have a tool that is added to the build-chain.
I am wondering how to redirect stdout to all compiler consoles and also, how do I break when an error occurs while executing that external tool?
Answers are sought for modern common compilers. If there is a generic process or if it can be done automatically let me know.

Comment: The problem is that it should be portable

Answer (score 1):

in Visual Studio, simply have your external tool printf to stdout, and return a non zero code from main().

Comment: printf? I cannot use cout? How about GCC?